# I get the error "structuredClone is not defined" in retrieve source with salesforce cli

Tags: salesforcedx, sf-cli

When I am trying to deploy to Org with SF cli in visual studio code, I am getting error saying that 'structuredClone is not defined'.

I am using node-v20.10.0 version.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: that is also happening to me and can't find a way to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is an issue to the new version of extension Salesforce Integration Cli in Visual Studio.
To fix this issue you must to go back to the previous version. Only needed to got to the extensions and select the previous one.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Jose: which of the salesforce extension pack are you using?

Comment: Hi @KumaraRavuri , i'm using version v59.16.0 of Salesforce Extension Pack, but to Salesforce CLI Integration I'm using version v59.13.0. Of that way it's working correctly.

Comment: this is not a vscode issue. I tried manually writing the command but received the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Update your Vscode and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to the previous sf extension pack didn't work for me. My solution was:

Unistall Java JDK (I think its not necessary, I think its not really necessary to uninstall, but it worked for me)
Unistall Node.js (I think its not really necessary to uninstall, but it worked for me)
Unistall Salesforce Extension Pack In VsCode
Uniistall Salesforce CLI
Unistall VSCode

Install again VSCode
Install again Salesforce CLI
Install again the salesforce extension

It doesn't make much sense, but it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Updating my node.js to v21.6.2 works for me.

```
sudo n latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the same node version.

I used Jose's answer above to resolve it but with the following caveats:

1. Revert the Salesforce CLI Integration to 59.13.0
2. Revert ALL Salesforce Extension Pack extensions to 59.16.0, not just the Salesforce Extension Pack itself.